# NAudio Frame Streaming from a Source that has incoherent frames

Tags: c#, streaming, naudio

Please, how does one make sense, and read Frames like so:

[image]

```
if (decompressor == null || bufferedWaveProvider == null)
{

decompressor = CreateFrameDecompressor(frame);
bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
}

int decompressed = -1;

try
{

decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Decompression Error:\r\n {0}", exc.Message));
}
```

No Audio plays, no matter how I filter the Stream.

Uri: http://stream.radiometro.com.au:7777/;stream.nsv

Thanks to NAudio Coders!

Comment: Seems similar, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754560/naudio-select-the-proper-frame-for-acmmp3framedecompressor' but this does not appear to work.

Comment: Are you sure it's actual MP3 audio being received?

Comment: @MarkHeath - I cant be sure Mark. I am sure the stream work in HTML Page: https://radiometro.com.au/ using the same address. I used Debugger to check the Stream Address.